# Single Page Application - .htaccess config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vue.js

This is a VueJS application. I have a .htaccess file duplicated from any Laravel project like following;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is perfectly working what i want. But when I activated comment SSL Redirect rule lines redirects to SSL but routes not running index.html file, for example I have a /login route, /login request working without SSL redirect but if I add SSL redirect lines not working. Please show me when I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was configure my Digitalocean server manually, I've forget to enable rewrite in SSL virtualhost. That's a solution :)